# AWS Fargate backed EKS application not reachable over loadbalancer service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have created a Fargate backed EKS cluster and deployed an application listening to 9090. Remember I am using a label "worker: fargate" so that my apps are created in fagrate nodes and not on EKS worker nodes.

I have made sure the application is listening to ::9090 and respond well when performing with a curl localhost 9090

I then created a service of type loadbalancer with the below definition:

```js
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mytestapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mytestapp
    worker: fargate
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9090
      targetPort: 9090
```

I can see this has created a classic load balancer, under listener I see 9090 port and a random Nodeport.

The Loadbalancer backend health state shows "Outofservice" and telnet to the LB endpoint and port 9090 does not work.

I am confused what is wrong here. Note that I have opened security groups both inbound and outbound as well in the custer.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue that I should first create a service of type nodeport and then create an ingress resource to forward the traffic to this nodeport service. However after creating the same, my ingress do not have a class and host for it.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. You've created NodePort first and then deployed that `LoadBalancer` that you have and worrying that you don't have a class and host specified there? if yes, then you have to deploy `ingress` instead of `LoadBalancer` where you can specify the class(`ingressClassName`) as `fargate` and the host specified.